# create similar rapresentation to alt+m of string manipulation plugin but with intellij actions keymap

Tags: intellij-idea

this is what string manipulation plugin does for example use numbers to select the shown options

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHaG8.png)

I want the same rapresentation with this hierarchy actions to select with numbers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlKeq.png)

I've tried to add abbreviations, but nothing happened

Comment: Could you please provide information from "Help | About" (click on copy and paste data here)? I have shortcuts added to actions in that popup.